# Outlook Interop - 'Class' does not contain a definition for 'Property'

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, office-interop, office-automation

**Ultimate Goal/Frame Challenge:**

I'm trying to append the user's name and e-mail address to a template e-mail before sending it.

**Approach**

I'd like to use the DisplayName and SmtpAddress properties of the first Account in the  Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts collection using the below code. The e-mail template does appear, but the error occurs when I try to append the text:

```
var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

MailItem mailItem = outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplateEmail.FullName) as MailItem;
mailItem.Display();

mailItem.HTMLBody += (
    "For questions regarding this submission, please contact " + 
    outlook.Session.Accounts[0].DisplayName + " at " + outlook.Session.Accounts[0].SmtpAddress
);

mailItem.Send();
```

**Runtime error - not a compile error, Intellisense does like the properties**

> error CS1061: 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Session'

**What I've tried**

1. Close all open files in my solution
2. Get the latest Outlook.Interop via Nuget, Microsoft signed
3. Remove the older Outlook.Interop reference
4. Save and close Visual Studio
5. Delete my bin and obj folders and my solution's .suo file
6. Restart my computer
7. Re-open the project in Visual Studio
8. Build --> Clean solution; Build --> Rebuild solution;

**Outlook.Application properties at the time of the error**

```
{Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass}
    AnswerWizard: '((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass)outlook).AnswerWizard' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
    Application: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass}
    Assistance: {System.__ComObject}
    Assistant: {System.__ComObject}
    COMAddIns: {System.__ComObject}
    Class: olApplication
    DefaultProfileName: "Outlook"
    Explorers: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorersClass}
    FeatureInstall: msoFeatureInstallOnDemand
    Inspectors: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsClass}
    IsTrusted: false
    LanguageSettings: {System.__ComObject}
    Name: "Outlook"
    Parent: null
    PickerDialog: {System.__ComObject}
    Reminders: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RemindersClass}
    Session: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass}
    TimeZones: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.TimeZonesClass}
    Version: "16.0.0.14326"
```

I'm using 64-bit Outlook 365 on 64-bit Windows 10 for a 64 bit C# application.

---

Follow up question:
[C# class instance displays property values but does not allow direct referral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216339/c-sharp-class-instance-displays-property-values-but-does-not-allow-direct-referr)

Answer (score 0):

All Outlook collections are 1 based, not 0. Use `outlook.Session.Accounts[1].DisplayName`.

Also, do not concatenate strings when building an HTML body. You need to insert your string inside the existing HTML body.

Thirdly, try to break that line and explicitly define variables:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application(); 
Outlook.Namespace ns = app.Session;
```

Comment: These are good tips but don't address my question. (To be 100% clear, `outlook.Session.Accounts[1].DisplayName` still yields
`error CS1061: 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Session'` as expected given that it can't even find Session, let alone Accounts.)

Comment: The issue is not related to the index used.

Comment: Break that line and explicitly define variables: `Outlook.Application app = Outlook.Application(); Outlook.Namespace ns = app.Session;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately/predictably, `error CS1061: 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Session'`. We're not really zeroing in on the root of the issue here.

Comment: error CS1061 is compile time error, not run-time. Are you sure you get the error when **running**, not when compiling?

Comment: Also, get rid of the nuget package, add the reference directly, either from the COM tab, or by referencing the interop dll.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use a well-formed HTML markup when setting the `HTMLBody` property, for example, concatenating string doesn't work in the following way:

```
mailItem.HTMLBody += (
    "For questions regarding this submission, please contact " + 
    outlook.Session.Accounts[0].DisplayName + " at " + outlook.Session.Accounts[0].SmtpAddress
);
```

Instead, you need to find the opening `<body>` and closing `</body>` tags and paste the string between them. In that case you will get a well-formed HTML document which represents the message body.

To avoid errors with member definitions you need to declare the Outlook Application instance in the following way:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```

Also, try to add a COM reference manually in VS instead of using any NuGet packages:

```
Get the latest Outlook.Interop via Nuget, Microsoft signed
```

If you have multiple profile configured you need to use the `Logon` method to log into one of the profiles.

Then use the `GetNamespace("MAPI")` method instead of calling the `Session` property.

Be aware, the `Send` method may trigger security prompts or issues when Outlook is automated from external applications:

```
mailItem.Send();
```

You can read more about that in the [Outlook Object Model Security Warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/outlook-object-model-security-warnings) article.

Comment: These are good tips but don't address my question. Using all three together of explicitly typing outlook, using outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts[1].DisplayName, and using outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Logon() all lead to a similar error situation: error `CS1061: 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'GetNamespace'`. The problem here is that, for some reason, the program doesn't seem to be recognizing/able to use the properties of Outlook.Application() at runtime. What do you think of the properties state I posted above at the end of my question?

Comment: Have you tried to replace any PIA NuGet packages with COM references added instead?

Comment: Good question - I actually had the COM references initially and then replaced them with PIA Nuget packages when I was trying to resolve this error. Would you like me to revert that?

Comment: (Side note, my tip for you regarding explicit typing, it's more useful when the command is not literally `= new (exactly the desired type)`. For example, for Excel.Interop, you do need to do `Range range = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[], worksheet.Cells[]]`).

Comment: Have you tried to create a new project and then add COM references there. Does it work correctly in that case?