# C# class instance displays property values but does not allow direct referral

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop, com-interop

Why would `outlook.Version` display `error CS1061: 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Version'` when the value is clearly `16.0.0.14326`?

Building on this question:
[Outlook Interop - 'Class' does not contain a definition for 'Property'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73212341/outlook-interop-class-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-property)

I think I've zeroed in on what the issue is here. Printing the `outlook` instance in the immediate window yields this:

```
{Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass}
    AnswerWizard: '((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass)outlook).AnswerWizard' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
    Application: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass}
    Assistance: {System.__ComObject}
    Assistant: {System.__ComObject}
    COMAddIns: {System.__ComObject}
    Class: olApplication
    DefaultProfileName: "Outlook"
    Explorers: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorersClass}
    FeatureInstall: msoFeatureInstallOnDemand
    Inspectors: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsClass}
    IsTrusted: false
    LanguageSettings: {System.__ComObject}
    Name: "Outlook"
    Parent: null
    PickerDialog: {System.__ComObject}
    Reminders: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RemindersClass}
    Session: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass}
    TimeZones: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.TimeZonesClass}
    Version: "16.0.0.14326"
```

But trying to print literally any property of the `outlook` instance, even ones that should seemingly give straightforward values like `outlook.Version`, gives me `does not contain a definition for` errors. Intellisense happily autofills these properties and at least some of them clearly have values. What's going on?

---

Update, following @SimonMourier's suggestion to use:

`dynamic outlook = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application"));`

works, and I'd love to understand more about why it does. For example, it returns exactly the same values when the instance is printed:

```
{Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass}
    AnswerWizard: '((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass)outlook).AnswerWizard' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
    Application: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass}
    Assistance: {System.__ComObject}
    Assistant: {System.__ComObject}
    COMAddIns: {System.__ComObject}
    Class: olApplication
    DefaultProfileName: "Outlook"
    Explorers: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorersClass}
    FeatureInstall: msoFeatureInstallOnDemand
    Inspectors: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsClass}
    IsTrusted: false
    LanguageSettings: {System.__ComObject}
    Name: "Outlook"
    Parent: null
    PickerDialog: {System.__ComObject}
    Reminders: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RemindersClass}
    Session: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass}
    TimeZones: {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.TimeZonesClass}
    Version: "16.0.0.14326"
```

So why do they not return property values in the same way? Why do I get definition errors with `new Outlook.Application()` but no definition errors with `Activator.CreateInstance()`?

---

In making an MVC example for @SimonMourier, I performed the following steps:

1. New C# .NET Framework 4.7.2 console desktop app project
2. Add Reference --> COM --> Outlook 16.0 Object Library
3. Added the below code to Main():

   ```
   dynamic outlook2 = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application"));
   var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
   Console.WriteLine(outlook.Version);

   outlook2.Quit();
   outlook.Quit();
   ```
4. Break on `outlook2.Quit();`
5. As written, outlook.Version properly returns "16.0.0.14326"
6. When commenting out `Console.WriteLine(outlook.Version);`, outlook.Version returns `error CS1061: 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Version'`
7. outlook2.Version always properly returns "16.0.0.14326"

Why does writing a value to the console affect the ability to properly return a property?

Comment: I see `outlook` referred to as both `Application` (in the error message) and `ApplicationClass` (in the property list). Those are different types.

Comment: How did you add the reference?

Comment: @shingo I added these references by installing the PIAs from Nuget - they were automatically added to References afterward.

Comment: I added it with *Add > COM Reference > Microsoft Outlook x.x Object Library*, you may have a try.

Comment: @shingo I removed all references to Interop Outlook, uninstalled the Nuget package, cleaned my solution, added a COM reference, rebuilt my solution, same issue:
`outlook.Version error CS1061: 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Version'`

Comment: Is this a problem only when building and only with Version property?

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or Core 3/5/6? Does this (.NET framework) work: `dynamic outlook = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application"));Console.WriteLine(outlook.Version);` if yes, can you post a fully reproducible project somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new project with a target .net framework 4.5-4.8 and then add COM references there. Does it work?

Comment: @shingo "But trying to print literally any property of the outlook instance, even ones that should seemingly give straightforward values like outlook.Version, gives me does not contain a definition for errors."

Comment: @SimonMourier Hey, this is working! It's returning "16.0.0.14326" for the version. Why is that? I'd love to hear more. (To answer your other question, I'm on .NET Framework 4.7.2) I'll try to figure out where I can post a project for you - maybe just in the question above unless you have a suggestion for website to upload to.

Comment: Glad it works (I'm not suprised, dynamic is just the most simple way to use COM automation object model - IDispatch based - but it can be tedious when models are big, like with Office apps). You can post a reproducing project anywhere you like on the internet

Comment: @SimonMourier Update posted, thanks for your help. I'm definitely going to be using your Activator and dynamic procedure going forward - I could see while messing around with the MVC that even typing your Activator as Outlook.Application() instead of dynamic broke the property definitions again, whereas if I leave it alone it will happily return the .Session.Accounts[1].DisplayName and .SmtpAddress that I want. Weird and frustrating to not be able to use Intellisense meaningfully with Outlook COM objects, but "actually works" is always priority #1. Post `Activator()` as answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually cannot reproduce the problem in the question, but another way of calling COM object that support [COM Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/automation) (IDispatch interface, typelibs, etc.) such as Microsoft Office Applications is to use the [C# dynamic keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) that was introduced with C# 4.

So, in the Outlook example, you can just create the [Outlook Application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application) with this code (without creating any reference or using any PIA, you just need Outlook to be installed correctly):

```
dynamic outlook = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application"));
```

And then call any method or property just as you would if autocompletion did not exist:

```
Console.WriteLine(outlook.Version); // C# will dynamically call for a property named "Version"
```

Notes: name resolution happens at runtime, and the main drawback is you don't have autocompletion, so, with big models hierarchies like Outlook, it can be difficult to work with.